Structure of a Finite Group Generated by Two Elements with a Specific Commutation Relation
Let G be a finite group generated by two elements, i.e., there exist two elements $ a $ and $ b$ such that $ G = \langle a,b\rangle $
Furthermore, assume there exists an $ l \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $ ab=ba^l $.
Show that it follows:
$ G = \{a^mb^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $
I tried to proof it by induction: Starting with products of one factor, it is easy to express each product in the desired form.
Assuming that a product of  k  factors can be written as  $ a^mb^n $, I then attempted to extend this to products of  k+1  factors by considering cases where the last factor is  $a$ or $b$, and simplifying accordingly. But I got stuck with the case where the last factor is $a$.

Do induction over the number of $a$'s that are in a word before a $b$.

You have to use the fact that $G$ is finite. The statement is not true in general for infinite groups.

I assume you mean $G= \langle a, b \rangle$.  Here's the intuition.  Any element of $G$ can be written in the form $a^{m_1}b^{n_1} \cdots a^{m_k}b^{n_k}$.  Use the commutation relationship to "move" all of the $a$s to the left, collecting all of the $a$s and all of the $b$s.

If you know what to do whenever the last factor is not $a$, then just add a $b^n$ with $n$ the order of $b$ at the end.

Observation 1. Because $G$ is finite, for every integer $k$ there exists a nonnegative integer $r$ such that $a^k=a^r$, and similarly for  $b$.
Proof. Since $G$ is finite, $a$ has finite order, say order $n\gt 0$. Write $k=qn+r$ with $0\leq r\lt n$. Then $a^k = a^{qn+r} = (a^n)^qa^r = a^r$. Similarly for $b$.
Observation 2. If $k$ is a positive integer, then $a^kb=ba^{k\ell}$.
Proof. Induction on $k$. This holds for $k=1$ by assumption. Assuming it holds for $k$,
$$a^{k+1}b = a(a^kb) = a(ba^{k\ell}) = (ab)a^{k\ell} = ba^{\ell}a^{k\ell} = ba^{\ell+k\ell} = ba^{(k+1)\ell}.$$
Observation 3. For any positive integer $r$, $ab^r = b^ra^{\ell^r}$.
Proof. True for $r=1$. Assuming this is true for $k$, wee have
$$ab^{k+1} = (ab^k)b = (b^ka^{\ell^k})b = b^k(a^{\ell^k}b) = b^k(ba^{\ell^k\ell}) = b^{k+1}a^{\ell^{k+1}}.$$
Observation 4. For any positive integers $r$ and $t$, $a^rb^t = b^ta^{r\ell^t}$
Proof. Fix $t$. For $r=1$, this is Observation 3. Assuming it holds for $k$, we have
$$a^{k+1}b^t = a(a^kb^t) = a(b^ta^{k\ell^t}) = (ab^t)a^{k\ell^t} = b^ta^{\ell^t}a^{k\ell^t} = b^t a^{\ell^t+k\ell^t} = b^ta^{(k+1)\ell^t}.$$
Observation 5. Every element of $G$ can be written in the form
$$b^{m_1}a^{n_1}\cdots b^{n_s}a^{m_s}\tag{$*$}$$
with $s\geq 1$, $m_i,n_j\gt 0$ for all $i,j$.
Proof. Every element of $G$ is a product of powers of $a$ and $b$. Using Observation 1, we can replace any exponent with a nonnegative exponent; remove all exponents equal to $0$ and consolidate. If the word does not being with a power of $b$, add $b^r$ (where $b$ is of order $r$) at the beginning, and if it does not end with a power of $a$ then add $a^t$ with $t$ the order of $a$ at the end.
Observation 6. Every element of $G$ can be written in the form $b^ra^s$ with $r$ and $s$ positive integers.
Proof. Write an element of $G$ in the form $(*)$. We proceed by induction on $s$.
If $s=1$, then we are done. Assuming the result holds for $k$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
b^{m_1}a^{n_1}b^{m_2}\cdots b^{n_{k+1}}a^{m_{k+1}} &=
b^{m_1}b^{m_2}a^{n_1\ell^{m_2}}a^{n_2}\cdots b^{n_{k+1}}a^{m_{k+1}}\\
&= b^{m_1+m_2}a^{n_1\ell^{m_2}+n_2}\cdots b^{n_{k+1}}a^{m_{k+1}}.
\end{align*}$$
This expression has $k$ terms of the form $b^ia^j$, so by induction it can be written as $b^ra^s$ for some positive integer $r$ and $s$.
Thus, every element of $G$ can be written in the form $b^ra^s$.
Now let $g\in G$. Then $g^{-1}$ can be written as $g^{-1}=b^ra^s$, which means that $g=a^{-s}b^{-r}$, which expresses $g$ in the desired form. (In fact, we can now turn the exponents nonnegative using Observation 1)
Conversely, since $a,b\in G$, then $a^mb^n\in G$ for every integers $m$ and $n$.

You can do this with any word in $a$ and $b.$
If you have a word in $a$ and $b$ which ends in $a,$ for instance
$$ababa,$$  rewrite it using the "anti-commutativity" $$ab=ba^l,$$ repeatedly.
So here we get: $$ab(\color{blue}{ab})a=ab(\color {blue}{ba^l})a=ab^2a^{l+1}=(\color{blue}{ab})ba^{l+1}=(\color{blue}{ba^l})ba^{l+1}=b(\color{red}{a^lb})a^{l+1}. $$
Then we need an expression for $a^lb.$  But  $$\color{red}{a^lb}=a^{l-1}ab=a^{l-1}ba^l=a^{l-2}(ab)a^l=a^{l-2}(ba^l)a^l=a^{l-2}(ba^{2l})=\cdots =aba^{(l-1)l}=ba^la^{(l-1)l}=\color{red}{ba^{l^2}}.$$
Plug that in to get:   $$b(ba^{l^2})a^{l+1}=b^2a^{l^2+l+1}.$$
Note:  to correct for the order of $a$ and $b,$ do this sort of process to the inverse of the word you started with. Then take inverses again.
That's $ababa=(a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1})^{-1}.$
So the computation above actually shows that $$a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}=(b^2a^{l^2+l+1})^{-1}=a^{-(l^2+l+1)}b^{-2}.$$

@Arturo I begrudge you noticing the lack of symmetry.  And finding the correction.

Note:   unlike you "guys" I can't upvote my own answers and comments
